# How to query 5 users in random who have published more than 10 posts

Tags: wp-query, users, query, wp-user-query

I want to display 5 users who have published more than 10 posts, when the page loaded again, it should show another 5 users or mixed with new users with more than 10 posts.

How do I achieve this? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it should work for you

In your `function.php` to make random order available in WP_User_Query

```
function my_random_user_query( $class ) {
 if( 'rand' == $class->query_vars['orderby'] )
 $class->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', 'RAND()', $class->query_orderby );
 return $class;
}
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'my_random_user_query' );
```

[Source](http://www.codecheese.com/2014/05/order-wordpress-users-random/)

And a query like this

```
// Get all users id
$args = array (
 'has_published_posts' => true,
 'fields' => 'ids',
);
$wp_users = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$ids_users = $wp_users->get_results();

// Return users id with more than 10 posts
$users = array_filter($ids_users, function($id){
  $count = count_user_posts( $id );
  if($count >= 10) return $id;
});

// Get users previously filtered 
$args = array (
 'orderby'    => 'rand',
 'include'    => $users,
 'number' => 5
);
$wp_users = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$result = $wp_users->get_results();
```

[Codex query about users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Return_Values)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. You just saved my ass, bro. By the way, `add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'my_random_user_query' );` should be added to the above function lines.

Comment: Then I have a custom meta for users `simple_local_avatar`. How do I filter (display) the users who have uploaded local avatar ? I'll appreciate so much if you can help with this.